# WPF InitializeComponent() gives CS0103 error when adding image with SplashScreen Buid Action

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen

I'm facing some sort of odd issue that I cannot explain to myself (hence fix):
In my C# application I have 3 WPF Windows that will pop up when called. Of course, all those WPF windows have the `InitializeComponent()` method.

I have also created a `SplashWindow` custom class where I define a SplashScreen generic window. Requiring a `Uri` object as input it will pop up a splash screen with the image referring to that Uri and then close, when called the closing method. The image I use for the splash screen is loaded in my solution in a folder named *Resources* and the **Build Action** is set to **SplashScreen**.
Here is the code:

```
    class SplashWindow
{
    private Form form = null;

    public SplashWindow(Uri uri)
    {
        form = new Form();

        StreamResourceInfo info = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

        Image splashImage = Image.FromStream(info.Stream);

        // Get image dimensions
        form.Width = splashImage.Width;
        form.Height = splashImage.Height;            

        form.BackgroundImage = splashImage;

        form.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;

        form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        form.TopMost = true;

        form.Show();
    }

    internal void CloseSplash()
    {
        form.Close();
    }
}
```

And I call this splash screen object once in my code in something like this:

```
// Start async to get user
Task<User> getUser = GitHubConnection.LoginAsync(tok);

// Pop up splash screen in the meantime
SplashWindow splash = new SplashWindow(validationUri);

// Await for user
User user = await getUser;

// Close splash screen
splash.CloseSplash();
```

And this works perfectly!

**The problem I'm facing** is that if I try to add another image to my solution and set the Build Action to SplashScreen to the newly updated image, then all the `InitializeComponent()` methods in ALL my WPF windows start giving a CS0103 error: `The name InitializeComponent does not exist in current context`. So it's like I can't use more than one splash screen, but this doesn't make any sense to me.

Any idea why this is happening? What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure of issue, but if you are opening/closing the splash screen yourself in the code then you do not need to set the image build action as splash screen. Just set it as a resource. Also if you set the build action as spalsh screen you do not need to wire up the code to display that, WPF automatically does that for you.

Comment: @peeyushsingh you're right! it works! thanks!!
I'd still be curious to understand what's the issue, but this will do for now

Comment: Not sure of the reason about why we cant have more than 1 splash screen (basically if we want more than 1 screen then we need to code it up ourselves, which looks a sensible choice). But when I do add more than one screen in a dummy project I do get the nice error: 1>`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFx.targets(268,9): error MC1004: Project file cannot specify more than one SplashScreen element.`